# Which is better: Foreign Keys or Model Inheritance?

Tags: django, django-models

I have this use case scenario:
there are places which are either playgrounds, restaurants, theatres, pubs. 
the same `place` can have playgrounds, restaurants, theatres etc. 
there are couple of ways of implementing it:

1. use foreign keys

   ```
   class Place(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

   class PlayGrounds(models.Model)
       field1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
       place = models.ForeignKey(Place)
   ```
2. multitable inheritance

   ```
   class Place(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
       address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

   class Restaurant(Place):
       serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField()
       serves_pizza = models.BooleanField()
   ```
3. use abstract class

   ```
   class Place(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

   class PlayGrounds(Place)
       field1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
       place = models.ForeignKey(Place)
       class Meta:
           abstract = True
   ```
4. use proxy models

   ```
   class Place(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

   class PlayGrounds(Place)
       field1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
       place = models.ForeignKey(Place)
       class Meta:
           proxy = True
   ```

What are the pros and cons of using each approach?

Comment: You need to tell us more about what you're doing with these objects and classes before we can help you.

Comment: well if you take a look into it, i just wanted to ask which method of implementation is preferred at what place? this is more of an architectural question.

Comment: The "architectural" question cannot be answered in the abstract.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first one *is* essentially model inheritance, because that's what Django's implementation of MTI uses (except it's a `OneToOneField` instead of a `ForeignKey`, but that's merely a `ForeignKey` that's unique).

Anytime you have an *is-a* relationship (i.e., a Restaurant is a Place), you're dealing with inheritance, so using one of Django's model inheritance methodologies is the way to go. Each, however, has its pros and cons:

**Abstract Models**

Abstract models are useful when you just want to off-load repetitive fields and/or methods. They're best used as mixins, more than true "parents". For example, all of these models will have an address, so creating an abstract `Address` model and having each inherit from that might be a useful thing. But, a `Restaurant` is not an `Address`, per se, so this is not a true parent-child relationship.

**MTI (Multiple Table Inheritance)**

This is the one that's akin to your first choice above. This is most useful when you need to interact with both the parent and child classes and the children have unique fields of their own (fields, not methods). So a `Restaurant` might have a `cuisine` field, but a `Place` wouldn't need that. However, they both have an address, so `Restaurant` inherits and builds off of `Place`.

**Proxy Models**

Proxy models are like aliases. They cannot have their own fields, they only get the fields of the parent. However, they can have their own methods, so these are useful when you need to differentiate kinds of the same thing. For example, I might create proxy models like `StaffUser` and `NormalUser` from `User`. There's still only one user table, but I can now add unique methods to each, create two different admin views, etc.

For your scenario, proxy models don't make much sense. The children are inherently more complicated than the parent and it wouldn't make sense to store all the fields like `cuisine` for `Restaurant` on `Place`.

You *could* use an abstract `Place` model, but then you lose the ability to actually work `Place` on its own. When you want a foreign key to a generalized "place", you'll have to use generic foreign keys, instead, to be able to choose from among the different place types, and that adds a lot of overhead, if it's not necessary.

Your best bet is using normal inheritance: MTI. You can then create a foreign key to `Place` and add anything that is a child of `Place`.

Comment: somehow, i have always liked your answers, this being no exception. thanks!!

Comment: Hah, me too! Somehow, I think Chris actually knows what he's doing.

Comment: Wow, I like this answer. I have a related question that you maybe could answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761441/convert-onetoonefield-to-multipletableinheritance if you have time? It would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on what sort of behaviour you need.

Do you need to perform the same kinds of operations on places and restaurants or playgrounds?
Will you be checking if your services (restaurants etc) are in the same place? Is it meaningful to treat two places with the same address as being different, and their associated services as different?

Without knowing the answers to these sorts of questions, it is impossible to say which is the most appropriate technique, as **they are very different techniques, and not in general substitutes for each other.**

The use of inheritance should not be dictated by an pre-conceived notion about taxonomy, because it is not there to model taxonomy: it is there to provide function polymorphism (data member inheritance is there primarily to facilitate that).

Answer (score 0):

I'd vote for an abstract class if the domain dictates that a `place` cannot exist if it is not at least one of the others.

But if a `place` doesn't need to have anything on it you'd need multiple inheritance to accomodate the placemarkers (vacant lots)?

I imagine the pro's and con's revolve around your fondness of spurious database tables.  How does the ORM implement these solutions? Personally i'm not fond of having lots of single field tables but ymmv.

Answer (score 0):

I'd vote for the first one, because it's the most explicit. And I don't see any advatages of other methods.